# Google map disappearing in APEX region

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, procedure, geocode

I'm trying to display map in one of my apex pages region, this map will have draggable marker which links to text-fields on other region and displays geocode for latitude and longitude. Everythings works except one thing the map is appearing just for 0.5 second and disappears. I think the problem is somewhere within coding as I have other similar program where map works perfectly fine. I'm using PL/SQL to retrieve map from procedure in a database.

Here is my PROCEDURE:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SHOW_LOCATION (
    map_div IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'map-canvas',
    issue_street_address IN VARCHAR2,
    issue_post_code IN VARCHAR2,
    city IN VARCHAR2,
    lat_item IN VARCHAR2,
    long_item IN VARCHAR2)
is
    a_mapstr VARCHAR2 (32000);
begin
    a_mapstr := '

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var marker;
    function initialize(myAddress, myLat, myLng) {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }    
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('||''''|| map_div   ||''''||'),mapOptions);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { '||''''||'address'||''''||': myAddress},   function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var markerOptions = {
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    flat: false,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                }
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, '||''''||'dragstart'||''''||', function() {map.closeInfoWindow();} );
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, '||''''||'dragend'||''''||', function(event) {
                  document.getElementById("'||lat_item||'").value=event.latLng.lat();
                   document.getElementById("'||long_item||'").value=event.latLng.lng();
                });
            } 
            else {
                document.getElementById("'||map_div||'").innerHTML = "No mapdata found for given address. Did you enter a correct address?";
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ''load'', initialize);
</script>';
--

sys.htp.p (a_mapstr);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        raise_application_error (-20000, 'error in show_map: ' || SQLERRM);
  END SHOW_LOCATION;
```

This is my PL/SQL to call the procedure:

```
SHOW_LOCATION('map_canvas','P20_ISSUE_STREET_NAME','P20_ISSUE_POST_CODE','P20_CITY','P20_LONGITUDE','P20_LATITUDE');
sys.htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">');
sys.htp.p('initialize('||''''||'Leidscheplein, Amsterdam,NL'||''''||');');
sys.htp.p('</script>');
```

and here is my html code for the region:

```
<div align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your procedure code:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ''load'', initialize);
```

In your call:

```
SHOW_LOCATION('map_canvas','P20_ISSUE_STREET_NAME','P20_ISSUE_POST_CODE','P20_CITY','P20_LONGITUDE','P20_LATITUDE');
sys.htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">');
sys.htp.p('initialize('||''''||'Leidscheplein, Amsterdam,NL'||''''||');');
sys.htp.p('</script>');
```

So the region is rendered, and the procedure code is called. In this code is a call which is registered on the document onload event. Obviously, the document is not ready at this time.
Secondly, you run a script which again initializes the map. This one will instantiate because it is not delayed until the load event.
Shortly after, the document has been generated and the onload will fire, with no parameters. I suspect this causes the brief appearance of the map which then blips out.

Try by removing the onload code from the procedure, and use this code after the function call (jQuery is safe because apex includes it by default, unless you happen to be on version 3.2 or the like):

```
sys.htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">');
sys.htp.p('$(document).ready(function(){ initialize("'||'Leidscheplein, Amsterdam,NL'||'"); });');
sys.htp.p('</script>');
```

Comment: yeah, I see what you mean, and I agree however I tried to initialise map without    `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ''load'', initialize);`
and it does not seem to work after many different tries and testing I just found this to work. I find it hard to just call the procedure and display all the data that needs to be displayed. Can you guide me how can I change the procedure to make it work?

Comment: @UZIERSKI sorry, that was pretty dumb to not give any solution advice. I've edited it in at the end of the answer, try it out.

Comment: yes!!! it finally worked I just removed from the procedure and it worked. However I have to say this is very strange I tried this for over 5 days not trying different things and they did not wanted to work but suddenly after adding line testing it and removing it all works how is this possible? I'm also developing mobile app and i find this JavaScript really fiddly at times. So annoying anyway thank you :)

Comment: javascript isn't annoying at all :-) It just needs understanding, like any other programming language. In conjunction with how html and the DOM (and its events) works